# How do I log onto the blog to leave comments?

Tags: support, blog

I'm trying to leave a comment on the Stack Overflow blog to express my views like other users have done, but I don't know how to do it.

I've just checked https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-login But it didn't work. Does anyone know how to login so I can leave a comment?

Comment: I dont understand the reason to downvote . Whats wrong ? please comment

Comment: I'd put it down to your poor initial formatting. If you were to spend more time writing your question, you might get a more welcome reception. I've tidied up your post and given you a +1 now, as it is a valid question (I don't know how to do it either).

Comment: @Matt , u also dont know Log into blog to leave comment ?

Comment: No, I don't know either. The only thing I can think of is that comments are disabled on blog posts older than  `x` days; if this is the case, this could be better explained on the blog.

Comment: @Matt , yes , But many people commented on the blog Post , On that day itself when post published.So i wonder how did they login .I can see Super Users there like Coding HORROR ! :(

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying that **maybe** Stack Exchange have the option of automatically closing comments after `x` days turned on on the blog. [See here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Comments_in_WordPress#Commenter_Rules). All of the blog posts are quite old, so maybe they are too old to permit comments on them anymore.

Comment: @Matt , yes i know it Matt  , but at least i should be able to login To Blog ,and post my comment/view as soon as the post is published , i mean immediately after  minutes of post publishing

Comment: "Immediately after minutes" ...

Comment: @i-CONICA ,yes after,5,10 ,minutes from publishing the post.

Comment: I was just highlighting the contradiction in terms. Ignore me. :)

Comment: @i-CONICA , can u please answer the question?

Comment: I wasn't here to answer the question! But incidentally, I can't login either. But they're two distinct systems. The blog is a wordpress blog as you know, and not a part of the stack exchange system/software, so why would your account be shared with that?

Comment: @i-CONICA , its part of Stackexchange , but having less interaction of users like Users can see/read it only but its 100% owned by Stackexchange only . Can u check ? blog.stackoverflow.com   . This is blog Site of stackoverflow.

Comment: I know it's owned by/run by. I'm saying it's not the same software! The stackexchange software which holds your account information for the various stack exchange sites you frequent is not related to the blog. subdomain which runs wordpress, on a completely separate database.

Comment: @i-CONICA , yes u true but there should be a link to login or create account to post your comment, Correct? u can see Comments made by Pupular people on stackoverflow on Posts , How did they login?

Comment: Pratik - it is a separate system entirely! I am admin for the Security Stack Exchange blog, so I'll have a wee look at it and see if I can find an answer. But as a word of advice, you may wish to tone down your demands - they may put people off answering.

Comment: @RoryAlsop , ok  thanks please answer if you find it.

Comment: @RoryAlsop , Yes this site http://security.blogoverflow.com/ is also in WordPress like blog.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I know this Pratik - all the Stack Exchange blog sites are in WordPress. List here: http://stackexchange.com/blogs

Comment: I think comments are auto disabled after a while. Best wait for a new blog and see if we can comment or not.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - that could be correct. I have checked on the sites I can post comments on, and past a certain age, I can't. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @RoryAlsop yep, maybe 1-2 weeks?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot create an account on blog.stackoverflow / blog.stackexchange - they are not part of http://blogoverflow.com and operate with a completely different software configuration.

Fortunately, you don't need to.

[image: leave a comment UI]

On posts that allow commenting (*new* posts only), just enter your name and email address, and your comment will be posted under that name and displayed with whatever Gravatar is associated with that email address. Some folks don't like Gravatar - if that includes you, then that's ok, just don't comment (or use a fake email address).

Note that we get a lot of spam on these, and so if your post ends up looking spammy (because you used too many links, all caps, a fake email address, etc.) it'll get blocked until someone checks the spam queue and lets it through (6-8 weeks).

Answer (score 3):

Updated after further testing:

I am identified and can post comments on the Security, SU and DIY sites, but not on the Stack Exchange blog itself. Initially I believed it is a setting specifically set on the SE blog (blog.stackoverflow.com) however from a comment by @ShadowWizard I checked further.

I can comment on posts from June and July, but not from May, so the likely cause is a time lock - comments are not allowed on posts over about 4-6 weeks.

Comment: I mean blog.stackoverflow.com(This is not stackexchange).

Comment: Blog.stackoverflow.com is the Stack Exchange blog, Pratik.

Comment: Then security.blogoverflow.com is also exchange blog.dont u think?

Comment: No - security.blogoverflow.com is the blog for Security Stack Exchange. There are many stack exchange sites, and quite a few have blogs (I gave you a link listing them in the comments up there). They are all on wordpress, but managed separately, with admins and contributors chosen from those sites.